# Reproduce clip-path polygon for browsers not supporting it?

Tags: html, css

How can i reproduce the design (see below), so browsers that does not support clip-path polygon can see it? I want it to angle the top edge, without rotating 
 or skewing the entire div. Is that possible?

[image: design with angled edge]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="angledbox">
    <div class="textstuff">
    <p class="title">Title</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent malesuada, turpis vitae hendrerit interdum, mauris augue viverra enim, id ultrices dui felis scelerisque ligula.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.angledbox {
    background-color: #5EA359;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 6000px 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 6000px 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
.title {
    font-size:30px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.text {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size: 18px;    
}
.textstuff {
    width:20%;
    margin:auto;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

**DEMO**

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/BechGameplay/pen/wejVGL)

Comment: Just tossing ideas: maybe add a div with `::before`, then give it a huge `border` (look up CSS triangles/arrows). Or maybe have a child `div`, in the background, that you rotate. Parent div cuts off the pieces on the left or right with `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @domdom Thanks, ill look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have play around a bit with your code pen and I don't think you get it by using border triangles.

But maybe this help you a little bit. I used linear gradient, which most browsers can handle.

```css
.angledbox {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #5EA359;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.angledbox::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  content: '';
  background-image: linear-gradient( to left bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

Please add/replace this in your code pen.

Or here a full Example:

```css
.angledbox {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #5EA359;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.angledbox::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 80px;
 content: '';
 background-image: linear-gradient( to left bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}

.title {
 font-size:30px;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.text {
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-size: 18px; 
}
.textstuff {
 width:20%;
 margin:auto;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="angledbox">
 <div class="textstuff">
 <p class="title">Title</p>
 <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent malesuada, turpis vitae hendrerit interdum, mauris augue viverra enim, id ultrices dui felis scelerisque ligula.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Kinda worked the way i wanted it to.